# Pushing data from AppService to Client project

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use AppServices to communicate between two apps. However, it seems like the communication is restricted to the following: Client app sends some data to AppService, which returns it's own data.

Is it not possible to have event listeners in the client, or any other way of sending information from the service to the client without the client initiating a request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible but the App need to open the connection. After opening the connection hook a event handler to the event RequestReceived

```
gpsService = new AppServiceConnection();
gpsService.AppServiceName = "nl.sparked.gpsappservice";
gpsService.PackageFamilyName = "b4619a2e-4aa1-4b84-b444-c2c2750cb4c8_5q3b35137xmx2";
RemoteSystemConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new RemoteSystemConnectionRequest(remoteSystem);
var status = await gpsService.OpenRemoteAsync(connectionRequest);

if (status == AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
{
gpsService.RequestReceived += GpsService_RequestReceived;
}
```

In your appservice you can send the data:

```
var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
appServiceconnection = details.AppServiceConnection;

appServiceconnection.SendMessageAsync(new ValueSet());
```